# How to access an .xlsb file by php?

Tags: php, excel

I need to access an .xlsb file that does the same function as this code that accesses a .csv file:

```html
<?php
$file1 = __DIR__ . '/download/Trabalhos.csv';
$csv1 = file($file1);
foreach ($csv1 as $row1 => $line1) {
    $row1++;
    $column1 = str_getcsv($line1, ';');
    if ($row1 == 2) {
        $column1[6]."<br>";
        $valor1 = $column1[6];
    }
}

$file2 = __DIR__ . '/download/produtividade do trabalho.csv';
$csv2 = file($file2);
foreach ($csv2 as $row2 => $line2) {
    $row2++;
    $column2 = str_getcsv($line2, ';');
    if ($row2 == 3) {
        $column2[9]."<br>";
        $valor2 = $column2[9];
    }
}
$file3 = __DIR__ . '/download/inatividade do trabalho.csv';
$csv3 = file($file3);
foreach ($csv3 as $row3 => $line3) {
    $row3++;
    $column3 = str_getcsv($line3, ';');
    if ($row3 == 2) {
        $column3[0]."<br>";
        $valor3 = $column3[0];
    }
}

$total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3;

?>
```

Access the .xlsb file, scroll through the columns and rows, and display the row value on the screen.

**Example:** "Line 2, Column G(In this case, G = 6)
"A = 0
B = 1
C = 2)"
...

I want it to show me the value of row 2 that is in column G(6).

As in the first if ...

```html
if ($row1 == 2) {
        $column1[6]."<br>";
        $valor1 = $column1[6];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PHP Excel library](https://www.easyxls.com/component-excel-library) from [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com).

```
$xls = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
$rows = $xls->easy_ReadXLSBActiveSheet_AsList("Trabalhos.xlsb");
for ($row1=0; $row1<$rows->size(); $row1++)
{
    $rowLine = $rows->elementAt($row1);
        if ($row1 == 2) {
            $column1[6]."<br>";
            $valor1 = $row->elementAt(6);
        }
}
```

You can find some more code samples about [importing data from xlsb file](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/import-from-xlsb-file-format.html).

Answer (score -2):

For your purpose you can use [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: The most used library for handling Excel files in PHP is indeed PHPExcel, but it does not support xlsb files, only xls and xlsx files.